# knockout.js validation error count not setting

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm using the [knockout.js validation plugin](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/blob/master/README.md) and it's working perfectly for a validating a form that I'm using, however, it doesn't appear to be tracking the number of errors. When I submit the form, if it detects any errors it shouldn't submit, but it is submitting.

```
function EntryViewModel(fullName, addressLine1, addressLine2, city, state, ZIP, email) {

    //viewmodel code here
    //the validation messages are being set on my form so i figure listing all of the rules is not necessary

  self.submitOrder = function(){ 
     alert(EntryViewModel.errors().length); //displays 0
     if (EntryViewModel.errors().length == 0) {
          //submit
     }
     else{
         alert('Please fix errors before submitting');
     }
   }
 }

 EntryViewModel.errors = ko.validation.group(EntryViewModel);  //I also tried putting this in my viewmodel and it didn't do anything
```

I could be approaching this entirely wrong, I'm just basing it off of [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ericbarnard/KHFn8/) that is linked from the Github page for the project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried changing submitOrder to reference self instead of the function name

```
self.submitOrder = function(){ 
    alert(self.errors().length); //displays 0
    if (self.errors().length == 0) {
      //submit
    }
    else{
        alert('Please fix errors before submitting');
    }
}
```

and inside the function, make the group call

```
self.errors = ko.validation.group(self);
```

assigning to self.errors is actually redundant.  the group call will create an errors observable on self